# Homology out of Smith normal form: simultaneous or independent diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a PID (such as $\mathbb{Z}$) and $R^m\overset{A}{\longrightarrow} R^n\overset{B}{\longrightarrow} R^o$ matrices with $BA=0$ and Smith normal forms 
$A=P\underbrace{\mathrm{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_r,0,\ldots,0)}_DQ^{-1}$ and 
$B=P'\underbrace{\mathrm{diag}(b_1,\ldots,b_s,0,\ldots,0)}_{D'}Q'^{-1}$.

> *[Topology for Computing](http://books.google.si/books?id=oKEGGMgnWKcC&q=smith#v=snippet&q=smith&f=false)* by Zomorodian p.137-138 claims that $$\textstyle{\frac{\operatorname{Ker} B}{\operatorname{Im} A}\cong
>  R^{n-r-s}\oplus\bigoplus_i\frac{R}{Ra_i}.}$$

How can one prove this claim? Any reference in the literature would also be welcome.

The free part is clearly true, because $\mathrm{rnk} \frac{\mathrm{Ker} B}{\mathrm{Im} A}=\mathrm{rnk}\,\mathrm{Ker} B - \mathrm{rnk}\,\mathrm{Im} A=$ $\mathrm{rnk}\,\mathrm{Ker} D' - \mathrm{rnk}\,\mathrm{Im} D=$ $n-s-r$. But I'm not sure about the torsion part...

**Motivation:** Basically, my question is, if we have a finite chain complex of free modules, given by matrices $\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_m$, can be compute the Smith normal form of each matrix separately $\partial_i=P_iD_iQ_i^{-1}$ to obtain homologies, or must this process be done simultaneously so that $Q_i=P_{i+1}$? The software packages that I know only compute SNF separately for each matrix.

Edit: Hmm, since $0=BA=P'D'Q'^{-1}PDQ^{-1}$ implies $0=D'Q'^{-1}PD$, the automorphism $Q'^{-1}P:R^n \to R^n$ must map $\langle e_1,\ldots,e_r\rangle$ into $\langle e_{s+1},\ldots,e_n\rangle$.

How can I make this question get more attention?

Comment: I find the claim somewhat suspicious, unless $P = Q'$ here.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Do you have a counterexample? I've tried looking at $m,n,o=2$, but unsuccessfully. Condition $BA=0$ seems to be restrictive.

Answer (score 2):

$\ker(B)/\operatorname{im}(A)$ is just the kernel of the map 
$$\Phi:\operatorname{cok}(A)=R^n/\operatorname{im}(A)\to R^o$$ 
induced by $B$, from the cokernel of $A$ to $R^o$.

But $\operatorname{cok}(A)$ is isomorphic to
$$R/a_1R\oplus\dots\oplus R/a_r R
\oplus R^{n-r},$$
and $\ker(\Phi)$ must contain the torsion submodule $R/a_1 R\oplus\dots\oplus R/a_r R$, so, since $\operatorname{im}(\Phi)$ has rank $s$, 
$$\ker(\Phi)=R/a_1 R\oplus\dots\oplus R/a_r R\oplus F$$
for some rank $n-r-s$ free direct summand of $R^{n-r}$.

Comment: Why must $\ker \Phi$ contain $\frac{R}{Ra_1}\!\oplus\!\ldots\!\oplus\!\frac{R}{Ra_r}$, how is that a submodule of $\frac{R^n}{\mathrm{im}\,A}$?